# how to minimize $\sum_{ij}a_i a_j P_{ij}$

Tags: optimization, integers

I want to calculate the minimum of

$$\sum_{ij}a_i a_j P_{ij}$$

for different choices of $\{a_{i}\}$, under the conditions

$$a_i=\pm1,i=1,2\ldots,n,$$

and $P_{ij}$ satisfies
$$\forall i,j ,\quad P_{ij}=P_{ji}\geq 0, \sum_i P_{ij} =1.$$

Comment: @achillehui   sorry，I typed wrong about this problem, it is supposed to be "minimum"

Comment: You mean in a smarter way than simply solving the MIQP?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I am not quite familiar with MIQP, can it get an analitycal result? If not, I may prefer an analytical lower bound...

Comment: This is a standard mixed-integer quadratic problem, for which there exist many numerical solvers. I don't think you can get an exact analytical result here, unless I miss some trivial property.

Comment: I think this is what is called a *Max-Cut* problem. Or more specifically, the equivalent problem $\max_a \tfrac{1}{4}\sum_{ij} P_{ij}(1-a_ia_j)$ is a Max-Cut problem. A bit of Googling should reveal some good resources about it.